# Is it possible to live reload react-intl messages during development

Tags: react-intl

Is it possible to live reload react-intl messages during development(for default language)?

I mean like Hot Module Loading, only updated message should be affected. Any ohter solution without running extra script or refreshing whole page will work too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anybody need it, I wrote HOC for this;

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {IntlProvider} from "react-intl";

const url = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/";

class IntlLoader extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {initialLocale: locale, initialMessages: messages} = props;
        this.state = {locale: 'en', messages};
    }

    fetchLanguagesForDevelopment = () => {
        // if development, use hot loading
        if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
            this.setState({...this.state, loading: true})
            fetch(url + "reactIntlMessages.json")
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.json();
                })
                .then((messages) => {
                    this.setState({loading: false})
                    if (messages !== this.state.messages)
                        this.setState({...this.state, messages})
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({error, loading: false})
                })
        } else {
            const messages = require('../../dist/reactIntlMessages.json')
            if (this.state.messages !== messages)
                this.setState({...this.state, messages, loading: false})
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchLanguagesForDevelopment()
    }


    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.fetchLanguagesForDevelopment()
    }

    render() {
        const {error, messages, loading} = this.state;
        //if (loading) return (<div>Please wait...</div>)
        if (error) return (<div>Error While Loading Language</div>)

        return (
            <IntlProvider {...this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </IntlProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default IntlLoader
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `module.hot.accept` your **translated** messages and render it as argument. See this example in [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/v3.5.0/app/app.js

```
const render = (messages) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  // Hot reloadable React components and translation json files
  // modules.hot.accept does not accept dynamic dependencies,
  // have to be constants at compile-time
  module.hot.accept(['./i18n', 'containers/App'], () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render(translationMessages);
  });
}
```